# How do I specify target dependant prerequisits with GNUMake?

Tags: build-process, gnu-make

Say I have a list of source files like this:

```
SOURCE=aaa.src bbb.src ccc.src
```

I want to create a rule to build each corresponding target in its own folder, the name of which depends on the soruce file.

> Sourcefile ----> Corresponding output file / target
>
> ---
>
> aaa.src -------------------> aaa/aaa.out
>
> bbb.src -------------------> bbb/bbb.out
>
> ccc.src -------------------> ccc/ccc.out

How do I write a rule for this using GNUMake? My best effort was the following Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

CC=somecompiler

SOURCE := aaa.src bbb.src ccc.src
RTARGS := $(SOURCE:%.src=%.out)
TDIRS := $(addsuffix /,$(basename $(SOURCE)))
TARGS := $(join $(TDIRS), $(RTARGS))

all:$(TARGS)

%.out: $(SOURCE)     # Better source specification?
    @[ ! -d "$(dir $*)" ] && mkdir "$(dir $*)"
    $(CC) "$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $*)).src" "$@"

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGS)
    rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty $(TDIRS)
```

The problem here is, that any one target (i.e. `.out` file) depends on **every** source (i.e. `.src` file), instead of just the one that has the same basename. I could change the commented line to `%.out: %.src` but than the source file would have to be in the same directory as the output file. I could also compile it something like this:

```
%.out: %.src
    $(CC) "$>" -o "$*/$@"
```

But then make would always compile every target regardless of whether it already exists or not.

How do I get make to use the appropriate source file only. **What is the proper way of specifying dependences for each target separately in a generic rule?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU Make you can specify prerequisites separately from recipes and still have a generic / pattern rule for all `.out` files:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all :

SOURCES := aaa.src bbb.src ccc.src
OUTPUTS := $(foreach src,${SOURCES},$(basename ${src})/${src:%.src=%.out})

# Build dependencies in the form of x/x.out : x.src | x
define ESTABLISH_DEPENDENCY =
$(basename ${1})/${1:%.src=%.out} : ${1} | $(basename ${1}) # Also depend on the output directory.
$(basename ${1}) : # Rule to create the output directory.
    mkdir $$@
endef

$(foreach src,${SOURCES},$(eval $(call ESTABLISH_DEPENDENCY,${src})))

all : ${OUTPUTS}

# Generice rule for all .out files.
%.out :
    @echo "build $@ from $^"
    touch $@

%.src : # For debugging only.
    touch $@

.PHONY: all
```

Output:

```
$ make
touch aaa.src
mkdir aaa
build aaa/aaa.out from aaa.src
touch aaa/aaa.out
touch bbb.src
mkdir bbb
build bbb/bbb.out from bbb.src
touch bbb/bbb.out
touch ccc.src
mkdir ccc
build ccc/ccc.out from ccc.src
touch ccc/ccc.out
```

Note that it is more efficient and elegant to have order-only dependencies on directories and let make create them, than to have each recipe checking directory existence first.

Comment: Okay so basically what `ESTABLISH_DEPENDENCY` does, when called, is to create an empty rule that just specifies the dependencies and another rule, that creates the directory. Am I right? In any case, this is pretty crafty. Thank you!

Comment: @con-f-use Right. To be pedantic, it creates a dependency only and no rule for `.out`. And a rule for the directory.

Comment: Thanks again. Please disregard my edit, I complete overlooked that `all :` was already in right in the third line