# Can I use pattern in phony target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, phony-target

I'd like to declare `a-test`, `b-test`, `c-test` as phony targets. Can I declare:

```
.PHONY : *-test
```

instead of

```
.PHONY : a-test b-test c-test
```

Also, how about declaring `.PHONY : %-test`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Becase a `a-test` is not a file. It's just an action that runs a bunch of programs. Same case with other `*-test`. And I don't know what XY problem is.

Comment: If the aim is to avoid having to manually specify the `.PHONY` target names multiple times then you might want to look at ["Is there a mechanism for something like python decorators in GNU Makefiles?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726975/is-there-a-mechanism-for-something-like-python-decorators-in-gnu-makefiles).

Comment: @G.M. ouch.. thanks, con-f-use's solution there stands out for its sheer smartness and unreadability..

Comment: The [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) which @G.M. rightfully points out here is that we both don't find an obvious or simple problem where a pattern of phony targets would make anyhing easier/better in a makefile. So maybe we could help better if you explained what you really want to solve with your phony-pattern solution instead of us trying to search for an unfitting patch to the `.PHONY` mechanism.

Comment: @Vroomfondel the problem I have is I have more than three `*-test` targets, do I need to list them all in `.PHONY`, one by one?

Comment: Are their execution recipes and their dependencies identical/analogous? I suppose not, so is it such a big deal to write an extra ` .PHONY:`  for each of them? IOW  which percentage of saved makefile source stands in favour of the approach you are searching?

Comment: You only need to use `.PHONY` if there is a file of the same name. For example, if you had a file called `all`, `.PHONY all` would mean `make` would not look at the modification time of `all` for `make all`. It would consider the file `all` not to exist.

Comment: I can't find references to support it, but `.PHONY: *-test` seems to work.